# Java sort a Hashmap on Value

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

Learning Java as I go (Python background).  Simple word count program in Java 7 code (can not use J8!).

I have a hash map of word:count pairs.  Now I need to sort on count (decreasing order), and break ties with using word in alphabetical order.

Have read s/o and I tried a treemap but it does not seem to handle ties very well so I don't think that is right.

I have seen a lot of solutions posted that define a new class sortbyvalue and define a comparator.  These will not work for me as I need to keep the solution all contained in the existing class.

I am looking for feedback on this idea:

- iterate over the map entries (me) in the hashmap
- use me.getKey = K and me.getValue = V
- new Map.Entry reverse_me = (V,K) {not sure about this syntax}
- add reverse_me to a List
- repeat for all me in map
- List.sort { this is where I am unsure, on how this will sort and no idea how to write a comparator.  At this point each List element would be a (count, word) pair and the sort() should sort by count in decreasing and then by word in case of same counts in alphabetical order)

This would be the final output.

Is this a logical progression?  I can tell from the many posts that there are many opinions on how to do this, but this is the one I can wrap my head around.

Also, can not use Guava.

Comment: `TreeMap` handles ties perfectly (but the sorting happens on the key, not the value of course, use `TreeSet` for value ordering), the fault was most likely with your code. `HashMap` on the other hand cannot hold an order (except `LinkedHashMap`, but even that's not sortable).

Comment: First thing first, in [tag:java], you will need to learn about `Collections.sort(...)`, `Comparator` and `Comparable`. You will need that knowledge for solving your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `List` of `Entry` set from the map. Sort the `List` using `Collections.sort()`. You can pass the custom `Comparator` for sorting by `Key` when `Value`(s) are same.

```
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
{
  public int compare( Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 )
  {
    int result = (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
    if (result != 0) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: @fabian Updated the example. Thanks.

Comment: I used this and it worked in my application.  Besides being first answer I think it's a very intuitive solution for a coder with Python, not Java, background.  thx

Answer (score 1):

This collection reflects the correct order only as long as the map entries are not changed

```java
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entriesSet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> me1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> me2) {
                return me1.getValue().compareTo(me2.getValue());  
            }
        });
        entriesSet.addAll(map.entrySet());
```

Comment: I already used this accepted answer mostly because it came across first.  I do like this TreeSet solution though, it looks very straightforward.  As I learn more Java I hope to understand this.