# Sort HashMap by Value and Convert to New Map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I'm trying to convert a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` to `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>` while sorting by a particular inner `value`. My struggles aren't so much with the sorting, but the conversion in the process.

Given these child `Map` and 1 parent `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> man = new HashMap<>();
man.put("h_ratio", "0.45");
man.put("w_ratio", "0.75");
man.put("a_ratio", "0.19");

Map<String, String> bear = new HashMap<>();
bear.put("h_ratio", "0.23");
bear.put("w_ratio", "0.72");
bear.put("a_ratio", "0.95");

Map<String, String> pig = new HashMap<>();
pig.put("h_ratio", "0.37");
pig.put("w_ratio", "0.64");
pig.put("a_ratio", "0.81");

Map<String, Map<String, String>> unsortedOrganisms = new HashMap<>();
unsortedOrganisms.put("man", man);
unsortedOrganisms.put("bear", bear);
unsortedOrganisms.put("pig", pig);
```

How do I efficently create `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>` sorting by `a_ratio` such that the result is:

`{bear={0.95}, pig={0.81}, man={0.19}}`

The real size of `unsortedOrganisms` is 50,000, and the real size of each inner `Map` is 50.

[Research shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32496641) the most efficient way is likely to

> Create a `List` of `Entry` set from the map then sort the `List` using
>   `Collections.sort()`

However that example assumes the output `Map` is the same structure as the input map. Whereas my result requires conversion to a `LinkedHashMap` of type `<String, Boolean>`

Comment: "However that example assumes the output Map is the same structure as the input map" That example doesn't create an "output map". It creates a list, sorts it, and leaves it as a list.

Comment: Oh, right. But the first line is `Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();` which is then passed into the created `List`. I don't see how I in turn convert my `map.entrySet()` efficiently into the `List` I should create and then sort as shown.

Comment: My first lines would be `Set<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>>> set = unsortedOrganisms.entrySet();
        List<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>>> list = new ArrayList<>(set);` So I'm sorting a list that isn't in the correct format.

Comment: Incidentally, this is an awful way to store this data: define a class for the organism with three fields, one for each ratio; and actually store the ratios as a numerical type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java Streams to solve that:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Double> result = unsortedOrganisms.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), Double.valueOf(e.getValue().get("a_ratio"))))
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (d1, d2) -> d2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

The result will be this:

```
{bear=0.95, pig=0.81, man=0.19}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. I'll look into the inner mechanics now. Thanks. Will likely accept once I compare against efficiency with the other posts.

Comment: The results are in, and speed differences appear neglible so I've accepted your answer as it was first, compact and correct. Thank you. Speed Demo: https://pastebin.com/P3QLRX16

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest with streams:

```
input.entrySet().stream()
    // Get just the (key, a_ratio) pair
    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get("a_ratio"))
    // Sort the entries by value, descending.
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
    .collect(toList());
```

I have kept it as a list because it doesn't make sense for a map to be "sorted by value": maps are key-based structures. Were you to add another key/value pair to the map, you'd have to rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: I get your point, it will require a bit of a rework but will definitely avoid technical debt long-term. Currently I'm looping the sorted map and using the keys in various ways. But, I should create an Object with proper data types for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Oldschool version without streams:

```java
  public static LinkedHashMap<String, Double> sortOrganisms(Map<String, Map<String, String>> data, String key){

    ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Double> > organisms = new ArrayList<>(data.size());

    for (String name : data.keySet()) {
      Double value = Double.parseDouble(data.get(name).get(key));
      organisms.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(name, value));
    }

    organisms.sort(new Comparator<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Double> >() {
      @Override
      public int compare(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Double> o1, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Double> o2) {
        // reverse sorting by value
        return -Double.compare(o1.getValue(),o2.getValue());
      }
    });

    LinkedHashMap<String, Double> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Double> o : organisms) {
      result.put(o.getKey(), o.getValue());
    }

    return result;

  }
```

Comment: Your solution works, and is essentially as fast as the other solution. However, the other poster was first and provided a compact answer. Thanks for your time. I learned from your code too. Speed Demo: https://pastebin.com/P3QLRX16